# Android Device Monitor nexus 6p no storage shown like older phones

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio and just received my Nexus 6p but when I open Android Device Monitor I no longer have access to the "sdcard" location which of course I know is internal memory.  When on the phone I can see folder while using ES File Explorer and I can also see my programs created folder for storage.  When using these modes MTP (I see some folders but not all, to include my applications folder and several others that I can see directly on the phone), Charge Only (no folders) or PTP (photo's only).

Any help would be appreciated.

Before this I had been using a Motorola Maxx and could see my folder in Android Device Monitor without issue.